# Linq Projection to DTO for Nested/Hierarchical Collections

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a `User` and `Product` entities which are defined as follows:

```
public class User {

    Guid Id { get; set; }
    Guid ParentId { get; set; }       
    ICollection<Product> PermittedProducts { get; set; }
    ICollection<User> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Product {

    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    ICollection<User> PermittedUsers { get; set; }
}
```

Conceptually, a `Product` has a collection of `PermittedUsers` - ie users that can purchase the product. Additionally, each `User` has a collection of `PermittedProducts`, as well as a collection of child users, who also have their own collection of `PermittedProducts`.

I need to run a query via a repository to return a list of products.  The repository method and DTO are defined as:

```
  public ICollection<ProductListDto> GetProductsForUser(Guid userId) {
       // Linq query here
  }

  public class ProductListDto {

      int Id { get; set; }
      string Name { get; set; }
      ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
  }
```

The repository method needs to take a Guid `userId` and retrieve the `PermittedProducts` for that User **AND** the `PermittedProducts` for the user's children.

For example, if a product is available for a user and his two children, then the ProductListDto would have all three users in it's users collection.

As a further example, if a product is not available for a user, but it is available for his children, then this would need to be returned as well.

Both the `Product` and `User` are available as aggregate roots, so I can use either a `ProductRepository` or `UserRepository` to query through, via EntityFramework's `DbSet`.

At the moment my repository method is in the `UserRepository` (but could move to the `ProductRepository` if the query is simpler) and looks like:

```
 public ICollection<ProductListDto> GetProductsForUser(Guid userId) {
       // Linq query here - Set is the EF DbSet<User> 
       var products = from u in 
           Set.Where(x => x.Id == userId) //.... NOT SURE ABOUT THE REST!

  }
```

My problem is I cannot work out how to write the Linq query to achieve what I need to do!

***EDIT***

The answers so far don't address how to achieve the projection to the `ProductListDto`

Comment: Hi Graham. Are you sure you want to join these two things together in this way? You said they are both aggregate roots which to me would imply they are separate concerns?

Comment: Unfortunately this is how I have to do it.  Effectively it is retrieving a list of products based on a UserId (or list of UserIds).

Comment: If you **really** **really**  want to do it it will be something like:

context.Products.Include(p => p.PermittedUsers).Where(p => p.PermittedUsers.Any(u => u.Id == userId));

That should get you the list of products for a user.

Comment: Thanks Simon - this won't get the products for the user's children as well though?

Comment: My approach would be to also call .Include(p => p.Children) and then loop through those to get their products. Finally union those together if you want and call Distinct.

Answer (score 1):

How I would approach this is simply build a list of Id's from the parent UserId so this will contain the Parent UserId and all of it's ChildId's. From this list we can then select from Products where PermittedUsers contains one of these Id's. This is where you can get the product list from.

```
        var childIds = DbContext.Users.Where(x => x.Id == userId).SelectMany(y => y.Children.Select(z => z.Id)).ToList();
        childIds.Add(userId);
        var products = DbContext.Products.Where(x => x.Users.SelectMany(y => childIds.Contains(y.Id))).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
userRepository.Where(u => u.Id == userId && u.ParentId == userId)
            .SelectMany(u => u.PermittedProducts)
            .GroupBy(p => p.Id)
            .Select(u => u.First());
```

Line explanation
 - 1) Retrieves target user and his children 
 - 2) Select all products from user collection we get in first line 
 - 3- 4) Remove duplicates.

Note such linq can be translated into heavy sql query that can decrease performance. Maybe it is better to call ToList after lines (1, 2 or 3). Also it is possible to write your own SQL query, store them in sql server and call them from code by name.